# How do you get the latitude and longitude of the circumference of an arbitrary hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, projection

If the earth is divided in half by a plane perpendicular to the sub solar point. How would I find the lat and lon of the points along the circumference to the resulting circle?

Comment: I would convert the point to cartesian coordinates, find the perpendicular plane, sample the circle, and convert back to lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the direction of the sun is represented by the vector S, the equation of the great circle is, in spherical coordinates

```
Sx cosΘ sinφ + Sy sinΘ sinφ + Sz cosφ = 0
```